# File input meteor cfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, meteor

So i see this code on the Docs

```
 Template.myForm.events({
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
//Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
});
});
}
});
```

But i dont want the file upload inmediatly when i click "myFileInptu" , i want to store that value (from the input), and insert lately with a button, so there is some way to do this?

Also its there a way to upload a FSCollection without a file? just metadata

Sorry for bad english hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving what you want to requires a trivial change of the event, i.e switching from `change .myFileInput` to `submit .myForm`. In the submit event, you can get the value of the file by selecting the file input, and then storing it as a FS File manually. Something like:

```
'submit .myForm': function (event, template) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var file = template.find('#input').files[0];

  file = new FS.File(file);

  // set metadata
  file.metadata = { 'caption': 'wow' };

  Images.insert(file, function (error, file) {
    if (!error)
      // do something with file._id
  });
}
```

If you're using autoform with CollectionFS, you can put that code inside the onSubmit hook. The loop you provided in your question works also.

As for your second question, I don't think FS.Files can be created without a size, so my guess is no, you can't just store metadata without attaching it to a file. Anyways, it seems to me kind of counterintuitive to store just metadata when the metadata is supposed to *describe* the associated image. You would be better off using a separate collection for that.

Hope that helped :)